# Editable combobox binding

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

```
<ComboBox  IsEditable="True" x:Name="copynotesbox" SelectedItem="{Binding NotesID, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment ="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0"  Height="30" Width ="75" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="DarkBlue" VerticalAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding NotesCopyObs}" >
     <ComboBox.InputBindings>
          <KeyBinding Command="{Binding NotesID}" />
     </ComboBox.InputBindings>
</ComboBox>
```

above is my code where is a editable combobox. The box is bound to a `List` called `NotesCopyObs` but I want the option to type in a number and have it bind to `NotesID` if it is not on the list to select. The list numbers work perfectly. I cant find the answer elsewhere online

thanks for all

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please explain it properly.

Comment: duplicate ? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17805798/wpf-combobox-add-item-when-user-enter-text-in-combo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17805798/wpf-combobox-add-item-when-user-enter-text-in-combo)

Answer (score 0):

```
Text="{Binding NotesID, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

by adding this, the text field of the combobox started to work